# Change/Print results to Uppercase

Tags: python

I want to change an array from lower case to uppercase and print the result in Python.

In the following x will continue to print in lowercase.

```
x = ['ab', 'cd']
for i in x:
    i.upper()
print(x)
```

How do you write the code so `x = ['AB', 'CD]` when you print for x?

Comment: you have to add result `i.upper()` to new list and print this new list. Or print it directly in loop `print(i.upper())`

Comment: `print([i.upper() for i in x])`

Comment: Do you want to do it in-place or you want to preserve the original list @GeneralCorrespondence ?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

If you don't know how to use list comprehension then you can write:

```
x = ['ab', 'cd']

result = [] # create list for upper strings

for i in x:
    upper_i = i.upper() # create upper string
    result.append(upper_i) # add upper string to list

x = result # replace lists

print(x)
```

Comment: You can avoid the extra list by doing it in place! @furas

Comment: @DeveshKumarSingh I could avoid it but OP is beginner and I specially rewrite it in many steps. And probably OP choose my answer because it is not in one line.

Comment: OP is already chosen your answer! I wonder the downvotes are due to the simplicity but extra usage of space @furas !

Comment: @DeveshKumarSingh I think it is downvoted because of simplicity.  But all these steps and even empty lines are to make it more useful for beginner.

Answer (score 3):

You need to assign the uppercased characters back to the original string.

```
x = ['ab', 'cd']

#Loop through x and update element
for idx, item in enumerate(x):
    x[idx] = item.upper()

print(x)
```

Or by using list comprehension

```
x = ['ab', 'cd']
x = [item.upper() for item in x]
print(x)
```

The output will be

```
['AB', 'CD']
```

Answer (score 1):

list comprehension is best for this.

```
x = ['ab', 'cd']
x = [i.upper() for i in x]
print(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
x = ['ab', 'cd']
x = [i.upper() for i in x]

print(x)
```

output

```
['AB', 'CD']
```

Answer (score -1):

Can be done with list comprehensions. These basically in the form of
   [function-of-item for item in some-list]

in your case

```
x = [a,b,c] 
[i.upper() for i in x ]
```